# how to fix my code printing memory address

Tags: java, string

I can't figure out what's wrong here. my code is supposed to check how many times a state specific appears in a 1 column csv file. I think its printing the address its saved in but i don't know how to fix it. It should also be printing all states but it's not.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class csvtxt 
{
   public static void main(String a[])
   {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      String strLine = "";
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      try 
      {
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\dbb38\\Downloads\\customers_export_1111 - customers_export_1.csv"));
         while (strLine != null)
         {
            strLine = br.readLine();
            if (strLine==null)
               break;
            sb.append(strLine);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            list.add(strLine);
         }
         String[] state = new String[]{"Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"};
         String[] state1 = new String[]{"Alabama1", "Alaska1", "Arizona1", "Arkansas1", "California1", "Colorado1", "Connecticut1", "Delaware1", "Florida1", "Georgia1", "Hawaii1", "Idaho1", "Illinois1", "Indiana1", "Iowa1", "Kansas1", "Kentucky1", "Louisiana1", "Maine1", "Maryland1", "Massachusetts1", "Michigan1", "Minnesota1", "Mississippi1", "Missouri1", "Montana1", "Nebraska1", "Nevada1", "New Hampshire1", "New Jersey1", "New Mexico1", "New York1", "North Carolina1", "North Dakota1", "Ohio1", "Oklahoma1", "Oregon1", "Pennsylvania1", "Rhode Island1", "South Carolina1", "South Dakota1", "Tennessee1", "Texas1", "Utah1", "Vermont1", "Virginia1", "Washington1", "West Virginia1", "Wisconsin1", "Wyoming1"};
         int[] stateCounts = new int[state.length];
         for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) 
         {
            String wordToSearchFor = state[i];
            for (String state2 : list) 
            {
               if (state2.equals(wordToSearchFor)) 
               {
                  stateCounts[i]++;
               }
            }
            System.out.println(state[i] + "="  + "["+ stateCounts +"]");
         }
         //
         //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
         br.close();
      } 
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
      {
         System.err.println("File not found");
      } 
      catch (IOException e) 
       {
         System.err.println("Unable to read the file.");
      }
   }
}
```

And this is the output. As I said earlier, I think these are memory addresses but I don't know how to fix it

```
Alabama=[[I@1db9742]
Alaska=[[I@1db9742]
Arizona=[[I@1db9742]
Arkansas=[[I@1db9742]
California=[[I@1db9742]
Colorado=[[I@1db9742]
Connecticut=[[I@1db9742]
Delaware=[[I@1db9742]
Florida=[[I@1db9742]
Georgia=[[I@1db9742]
Hawaii=[[I@1db9742]
Idaho=[[I@1db9742]
Illinois=[[I@1db9742]
Indiana=[[I@1db9742]
Iowa=[[I@1db9742]
Kansas=[[I@1db9742]
Kentucky=[[I@1db9742]
Louisiana=[[I@1db9742]
Maine=[[I@1db9742]
Maryland=[[I@1db9742]
Massachusetts=[[I@1db9742]
Michigan=[[I@1db9742]
Minnesota=[[I@1db9742]
Mississippi=[[I@1db9742]
Missouri=[[I@1db9742]
Montana=[[I@1db9742]
Nebraska=[[I@1db9742]
Nevada=[[I@1db9742]
New Hampshire=[[I@1db9742]
New Jersey=[[I@1db9742]
New Mexico=[[I@1db9742]
New York=[[I@1db9742]
North Carolina=[[I@1db9742]
North Dakota=[[I@1db9742]
Ohio=[[I@1db9742]
```

Comment: `state1` is an array; that is how Java prints arrays.

Comment: You are printing state1, but state1 is an array. Maybe you mean state1[i]

Comment: You should not modify the question in that way, it's better to add a **Edit** section and the corrections.

Answer (score 1):

state1 is an array of strings, not an string:

```
System.out.println(state[i] + "="  + "["+ state1 +"]");
```

The array does not implement toString, so it prints the default object toString implementation, which prints the memory address.

**Maybe you wanted to write:**

```
System.out.println(state[i] + "="  + "["+ state1[i] +"]");
```

If not, you will need to transform state1 into a string yourself, or into a List (the List class has toString implementation).

Comment: Ok thanks! Do you know why it's only printing out to ohio when it should print all 50 states?

Comment: Not sure... the i for loop runs until the number of elements in the list.which depends on the number of lines in the csv file that is imported... You also modified the code. You should not do that kind of modifications. Now your line is System.out.println(state[i] + "="  + "["+ stateCounts +"]");

Answer (score 0):

When you print an array you need to use the following:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```